# When does a gradient vector of a function not exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question that gives me a 3d function and asks me to calculate the gradient vector of it.
This part I understand.
It then asks me to indicate the points at which it does not exist.
When does a gradient vector not exist? Is it when it equals to zero? Or does it mean when the function DNE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the gradient is defined as the vector of partial derivatives so that it will exist if and only if all the partials exist. A zero gradient is still a gradient (it's just the zero vector) and we sometimes say that the gradient *vanishes* in this case (note that *vanish* and *does not exist* are different things). A function can still be well defined at a point without the gradient existing, in fact a function can still be continuous without the gradient existing.

Comment: One might define $\nabla f(x) $ to be the unique vector $g$ such that $f(x +h) =f(x) +g^T h +o(h) $ as $|h| \to 0$ (assuming such a $g$ exists).

Comment: Thanks!
From what I understand tho, if a partial derivative of the gradient does not exist, it means that it is defined as a critical point.

Comment: @littleO That definition holds only for differentiable functions in which case it just reduces to the normal definition.

Comment: Is this critical point the point where the gradient does not exist? I don't believe so since, from what I have learned, this point is either a local/absolute maximum, minimum or saddle point.

Comment: A critical point is typically defined as a point in which the gradient vanishes. It'll be a local max/min or saddle depending on the definiteness of the Hessian.

Comment: So basically, a critical point is a point where the gradient does not exist?

Comment: No, I've emphasized that the gradient not existing and the gradient being zero are different. A critical point is a point in which the gradient is zero (but it still exists!). A point where the gradient does not exist is essentially a cusp where the function experiences some sort of turbulence in some direction. It's a point where the function fails to be partially differentiable in some direction.

Comment: With the definition I gave, which I like because it is valid in any finite dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$, existence of partial derivatives is not enough to guarantee existence of a gradient vector.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the clarification! An example of a gradient being non existing then is 
f(x,y,z) = ln| 2x - y + z|
when all variables are equal to 0?
Since you ln of 0 does not exist, that means that it cannot be partially differentiable at this point. Therefore, the gradient doesn't exist at this point.

Comment: Yes, that would be one example. The absolute value function itself is another.